# Java date field tolerating different locales/mistakes

Tags: java, date, formatting, locale

I am working on a Java project where as you can see from the code below I have a JFormattedTextfield. What I would like to do is to introduce some tolerance in the date field. Like if the user inputs 02.02.2010 or 02.FEB.2010 or 02/02/2010, it shouldn't give an error. I am trying to search for something similar, but all I can find is examples of Simpledateformat telling to use predefined format. Kindly let me know or give some pointers. Thank you.

`DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
 DateFormatter df = new DateFormatter(format);
 JFormattedTextField dateField = new JFormattedTextField(df);`

Comment: You can use multiple `try-catch-blocks` to find out which format the date has. Or you can use pattern matching for that.

Comment: Even so, I have declared a date format(dd/m/yyyy) already, if the date is not in that order, I get an error. For the way you said, I would have to declare multiple date formats. Doesn't seem correct.

Comment: And why do you declare a date format before knowing the format of the user entered date?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any other way to accept date. I am currently working on a delimiter so I can split it by either '/' or 'space' or '.'. Then I can process them individually. But without the locale set, that again creates a hurdle for me.

Comment: Just take a normal JTextField and check the pattern of the entered data. Or try to use the entered data to create date object. If this fails you can reject the form.

Comment: Ya. Doing that only now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a seed of an idea, basically what this is a "multi formatter".  What that means is, you can supply any number of `AbstractFormatter`s to it and when requested, it will scan through the list until it finds one capable of parsing/formatting the requested value.

It has limitations...obviously, you can no longer use a mask of any kind, as the `MultiFormatter` allows for any number of different, incompatible (as far as the mask is concerned) formats...

During testing, I did not that when the field was validated, it would always default to the first formatter (to format the given value).  You might be able to fix this, by keeping a reference of the last successful parser used to parse the text to it's `Object` equivalent.  Of course, then you would also need to be ready to discard this formatter if it was not able to format the given `Object` again and try the other formatters...

The long and short basically is, the resulting "value" was correct for what the user put in.  The way that the `MultiFormatter` is setup right now, the first formatter will become the "default" formatter for new values...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.DateFormatter;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter;

public class Test100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test100();
    }

    public Test100() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DateFormatter[] formatters = new DateFormatter[]{
                    new DateFormatter(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")),
                    new DateFormatter(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMM.yyyy")),
                    new DateFormatter(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                };
                MultiFormatter<DateFormatter> multiFormatter = new MultiFormatter<>(formatters);

                JFormattedTextField ftf = new JFormattedTextField(multiFormatter);
                ftf.setColumns(10);


                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                frame.add(ftf, gbc);
                frame.add(new JButton("Test Focus Lost"), gbc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MultiFormatter<F extends JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter> extends DefaultFormatter {

        private List<F> formatters;

        public MultiFormatter() {
        }

        public MultiFormatter(F... formatters) {
            addFormatters(formatters);
        }

        public List<F> getFormatters() {
            if (formatters == null) {
                formatters = new ArrayList<>(25);
            }
            return formatters;
        }

        public void addFormatters(F... formatters) {
            getFormatters().addAll(Arrays.asList(formatters));
        }

        @Override
        public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {

            String text = null;
            for (F formatter : getFormatters()) {
                try {
                    text = formatter.valueToString(value);
                    break;
                } catch (ParseException exp) {
                }
            }

            if (text == null) {
                throw new ParseException("Could not find valid parser for " + value, 0);
            }

            return text;

        }

        @Override
        public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {

            Object value = null;
            for (F formatter : getFormatters()) {
                try {
                    value = formatter.stringToValue(text);
                    break;
                } catch (ParseException exp) {
                }
            }

            if (text == null) {
                throw new ParseException("Could not find valid parser for " + value, 0);
            }

            return value;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually did the same.. :-) Thank you again. I am still searching how to close the thread.

Comment: You can either accept this answer, but only of it helped answer your question or delete the question altogether